# font-feature-settings: lnum 1; doesn't work with text font weight more than 500

Tags: css

I've imported Raleway font from google fonts and got shifted numbers in my page. The problem was partially solved with font-feature-settings: "lnum" 1; but seems it doesn't work with font weight more than 500. Am I missing something?

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,600,400i'); 

body {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "lnum" 1;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "lnum" 1;
  -ms-font-feature-settings: "lnum" 1;
  font-feature-settings: "lnum" 1;
}
```

https://prntscr.com/mkw48r

Comment: I have the same issue, not working with font-weight above 500.

Comment: I found an answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235471/opentype-settings-reset-by-font-weight-and-font-style-in-chrome